# Converting a nullable reference type to a non-nullable reference type, less verbosely

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Is there a way I can convert a nullable reference type to non-nullable reference type in the below example less verbosely?

This would be for when the nullable reference flag for the compiler is enabled.

When the nullable reference type is `null`, I would like it to throw an exception.

```cs
Assembly? EntryAssemblyNullable = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

if (EntryAssemblyNullable is null)
{
    throw new Exception("The CLR method of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returned null");
}

Assembly EntryAssembly = EntryAssemblyNullable;
var LocationNullable = Path.GetDirectoryName(EntryAssembly.Location);
if (LocationNullable is null)
{
    throw new Exception("The CLR method of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location returned null");
}

string ExecutableLocationPath = LocationNullable;
```

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you want when the value is actually null.

Comment: Well, they should never be null they are being returned from the CLR. I'm not sure how they can ever be null. I just wanted to make the nullable to nonnullable conversion warnings go away, without just putting warning suppressing mark up around them. If either is null it throws an exception and closes the program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [throw expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#the-throw-expression) with the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

```
Assembly EntryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ?? throw new Exception("The CLR method of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() returned null");
```